# Cython: Numpy array missing two first elements when obtained from reference

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

This is the weirdest error, I'm trying to get a numpy array from a c++ function returning a **reference** to a vector, the whole wrapped using Cython.

I can make it work returning a `vector<int>` instead of a `vector<int>&`, but I want to understand what is happening when working with references. Here is a way to reproduce the error:

#### cmyclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace vec {
class IntVector {
    private:
        std::vector<int> vec;
    public:
        IntVector();
        virtual ~IntVector();
        std::vector<int>& get_vec(); #return a reference !
};
}

#endif
```

#### cmyclass.cc

```
#include "cmyclass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace vec;

IntVector::IntVector(){
    for(int i=10; i<20; ++i){
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
}

IntVector::~IntVector(){
}

std::vector<int>& IntVector::get_vec(){
    std::vector<int> buff;
    buff.reserve(vec.size());
    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i){
        buff.push_back(vec[i]);
    }
    return buff;
}
```

#### myclass.pyx

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "cmyclass.h" namespace "vec":

    cdef cppclass IntVector:
        IntVector() except +
        vector[int]& get_vec()

cdef class IntVec:

    cdef IntVector* _thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._thisptr = new IntVector()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self._thisptr

    def __init__(self):
        pass  

    def get_vec(self):
        cdef vector[int] buff;
        buff = self._thisptr.get_vec();
        return np.asarray(buff)
```

#### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

sourcefiles  = ['myclass.pyx', 'cmyclass.cc']
compile_opts = ['-std=c++11']
ext=[Extension('*',
            sourcefiles,
            extra_compile_args=compile_opts,
            language='c++')]

setup(
  ext_modules=cythonize(ext)
)
```

You can compile using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

#### Usecase

```
>>> import myclass
>>> vec = myclass.IntVec()
>>> vec.get_vec()
array([ 0,  0, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```

You can see the two first values are set to zero (they should be 10 and 11) ! The code would be working fine if we were returning a `vector<int>` instead of a reference to a `vector<int>`.

Any idea why this is happening ?

## EDIT: Final Solution

Passing the vector as parameter.

#### cmyclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace vec {
class IntVector {
    private:
        std::vector<int> vec;
    public:
        IntVector();
        virtual ~IntVector();
        void get_vec(std::vector<int>&);
};
}

#endif
```

#### cmyclass.cc

```
#include "cmyclass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace vec;

IntVector::IntVector(){
    for(int i=10; i<20; ++i){
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
}

IntVector::~IntVector(){
}

void IntVector::get_vec(std::vector<int>& buff){
    buff.reserve(vec.size());
    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i){
        buff.push_back(vec[i]);
    }
    return buff;
}
```

#### myclass.pyx

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "cmyclass.h" namespace "vec":

    cdef cppclass IntVector:
        IntVector() except +
        void get_vec(vector[int]&)

cdef class IntVec:

    cdef IntVector* _thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._thisptr = new IntVector()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self._thisptr

    def __init__(self):
        pass  

    def get_vec(self):
        cdef vector[int] buff;
        self._thisptr.get_vec(buff);
        return np.asarray(buff)
```

#### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

sourcefiles  = ['myclass.pyx', 'cmyclass.cc']
compile_opts = ['-std=c++11']
ext=[Extension('*',
            sourcefiles,
            extra_compile_args=compile_opts,
            language='c++')]

setup(
  ext_modules=cythonize(ext)
)
```

Comment: Your c++ code returns a reference to a local variable which is pretty much a guaranteed disaster. There's probably a compiler warning about it...

Comment: Your function should be  either `const std::vector<int>& get_vec() const{ return vec;}` or `std::vector<int>& get_vec(){ return vec;}` or `std::vector<int> get_vec(){return vec;}` depending on what you want to achieve, but not returning a reference to temporary object, as DavidW pointed out.

Comment: You're right ! I fixed the issue by declaring the vector in the `.pyx` file and passing a reference as parameter. One question remains: is `np.asarray` creating a copy of the data in the array? Ideally I would like to avoid copying the data.

Comment: `np.asarray` only copies if it needs to. You could fairly easily check for yourself - write out the relevant memory addresses and see if they match.

Comment: It definitely copies, and probably twice (first to a Python list then to the array)

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid or at least limit the number of copies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main aim appears to be to let numpy use memory allocated in a C++ vector. To do this you might be better implementing the buffer protocol for `IntVec`. The Cython documentation gives an example for a [Matrix class based around a vector](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/buffer.html) which you could simplify (since your case is only 1D). All you really need to do is create the functions `__getbuffer__` and `__releasebuffer__` (the latter can be blank, as in the example documentation). (I don't think there's a huge value in copy/pasting the documentation here)

Doing so will allow you to pass an `IntVec` directly to `np.asarray`. The resulting numpy array will use the `IntVec` for storage and keep a reference to the `IntVec` to ensure that it isn't deleted. You can also use Cython memoryviews with this class (if that's helpful).